# Telegram API request with InlineKeyboardMarkup does not show the keyboard with the message

Tags: java, json, post, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I am trying to send POST requests via Telegram API but it doesn't go well with an inline keyboard. Although the message text is sent , no keyboard is shown.

This is my function :

```
public static void ApiToOpponent(InlineKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup, long chat_id, String text) throws IOException {
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> keyboard = keyboardMarkup.getKeyboard();

    URL url = new URL ("https://api.telegram.org/bot1778589497:AAE2CGovQ67.......bk/sendMessage");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setDoOutput(true);


    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    params.put("chat_id",Long.toString(chat_id));
    params.put("text",text);
    JSONArray field_of_buttons = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray row_of_buttons;
    for( List<InlineKeyboardButton> row : keyboard) {
        row_of_buttons = new JSONArray();
        for(InlineKeyboardButton button : row){
            JSONObject button_json = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray param_aray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject button_param = new JSONObject();
            button_param.put("text",button.getText());
            button_param.put("callback_data",button.getCallbackData());
            param_aray.put(button_param);
            button_json.put("InlineKeyboardButton",param_aray);
            row_of_buttons.put(button_json);
        }
        field_of_buttons.put(row_of_buttons);
    }
    JSONObject last_json = new JSONObject();
    last_json.put("InlineKeyboardMarkup",field_of_buttons);
    params.put("reply_markup",last_json);

    try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] input = params.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
    }
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String responseLine = null;
        while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(responseLine.trim());
        }
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
    
}
```

Json from the request is:

```
{"text":"Your opponent has been found. Make a move","reply_markup":{"InlineKeyboardMarkup":[[{"InlineKeyboardButton":[{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:0,0,,X"}]},{"InlineKeyboardButton":[{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:0,1,,X"}]},{"InlineKeyboardButton":[{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:0,2,,X"}]}],[{"InlineKeyboardButton":[{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:1,0,,X"}]},{"InlineKeyboardButton":[{"text":"❌","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:1,1,,X"}]},{"InlineKeyboardButton":[{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:1,2,,X"}]}],[{"InlineKeyboardButton":[{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:2,0,,X"}]},{"InlineKeyboardButton":[{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:2,1,,X"}]},{"InlineKeyboardButton":[{"text":":heavy_large_circle:","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:2,2,,X"}]}]]},"chat_id":"369439.."}
```

And the response from the request is `{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":2420,"from":{"id":1778589497,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"Minesweeper","username":"Minesweep..."},"chat":{"id":3694....,"first_name":"Qwzr","username":"Qwa...","type":"private"},"date":1619903986,"text":"Your opponent has been found. Make a move"}}`

Will be extremely happy to any response : )

Answer (score 0):

In this case , right json request is:

{"text":"Your opponent has been found. Make a move","reply_markup":{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:0,0,,X"},{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:0,1,,X"},{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:0,2,,X"}],[{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:1,0,,X"},{"text":"❌","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:1,1,,X"},{"text":"❌","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:1,2,,X"}],[{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:2,0,,X"},{"text":"⬜","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:2,1,,X"},{"text":"⭕","callback_data":"Tic_tac_move:2,2,,X"}]]},"chat_id":"177114...
"}